# ActiveAdmin - Is there a way to generate a CSV combining two models that belongs_to a parent one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model `User`, and 2 models, `Foo` and `Bar` that `belongs_to :user`.
The user model have `has_many :foo` and `has_many :bar`.

These associations are in `rails` app level, not `active_admin` level.

What I want is to generate a CSV from the user show page, which I already have, that combines the respective `foo` and `bar` attributes of a user.

Foo and Bar share some attributes, but not all, so I'm aware that some fields will be left blank.

Is there a way to do this in Active Admin?

I've tried with the `csv do` block but can't manage to get all the `Foo`s and `Bar`s inside the same csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own csv generation code. Here is some scaffolding code to get you started:

```
sidebar :foos_bars_as_csv, :only => [:show] do
  a(href: foos_bars_as_csv_admin_user_path) do
    'Download as csv'
  end
end

member_action :foos_bars_as_csv, :method => :get do
  # define your own headers
  csv_headers = ["Header 1", "Header 2"] # customize yourself
  foos = resource.foos
  bars = resource.bars
  rawcsv = CSV.generate(:col_sep => ",") do |csv|
    # here you could add headers
    # csv << csv_headers
    
    foos.each do |foo|
      csv << foo.build_csv_row # or something like this
    end
    bars.each do |bar|
      bar << bar.build_csv_row
    end
    
    csv << csv_row
    end
  end
  send_data(rawcsv, :type => 'text/csv charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%e-%H%M%S) + "User#{resource.id}-FoosnBars" and return
end
```

Good luck!