# Active Admin Export custom data in CSV format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin

I have a Author and Book model. This relations like in the below.

```
author has many books
book belongs to author
```

In authors page; I can export all authors in CSV format but ı want export all authors and author's book in the one csv file.
The sample output should look like this.

| Author | Book |
| --- | --- |
| Jack London | White Fang |
| Franz Kafka |  |
| George Orwell | 1984 |
| George Orwell | Animal Farm |

If author have not a book, book area is should be blank.
When I filter the authors by the name George Orwell, for example, the output should look like this.

| Author | Book |
| --- | --- |
| George Orwell | 1984 |
| George Orwell | Animal Farm |

I think need change a collection data. How can ı make overwrite default export csv method? Thank you...

Comment: plz attach your code @OguzTR

Comment: There are only model relationships that I mentioned above. And I have 6 recorded data. 3 author and 3 book. In active admin authors panel; ı want mentioned csv output.

Comment: You can [customize the CSV format](https://activeadmin.info/4-csv-format.html)

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66176709/790737